# Sinon library how to mock this async validateMyRequest function to disable the auth?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, supertest

**validateMyRequest javascript function is as per below **

this function validates the post api call .

```
file.js

// this function validates the token 
const validateToken = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await getAuthInfo(req);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }


// this function validates the post api call request  
const validateMyRequest = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await validateToken(req, res);
        if (!req.file || !req.body.filename || !req.body.filetype) {
            return res.status(400).send(
                {
                    code: '400',
                    message: 'Invalid request',
                },
            );
        }
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
    next();
};

// this function stores the file in database
const storeFile = async (request, response, next) => {
// logic to store file
try {
        const client = await connectToDB();
        const db = client.db('test');
        const fileCollection = db.collection('files');
        const fileRecord = { name: `${request.body.filename}`, type: `${request.body.filetype}` };
        const resp = await fileCollection.insertOne(fileRecord);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.json());
router.use(routeLogger);
router.post('/', upload.single('input'), validateMyRequest, storeFile);
module.exports = {
    validateMyRequest, storeFile, router,
};
```

fileTest.js - (unit testing with mocha, sinon and supertest)

there seems to be issue with below stubbing logic and test case fails with 500 and expected response is 200

```
const storeFileStub = sinon.stub(fileController, 'validateMyRequest').resolves(Promise.resolve('next()'));
```

> ```
> fileTest.js
>
> const fileController = require('../../../src/controllers/file.js');
>
> const app = express();
> app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
> app.use('/', packagesRoute.router);
>
>
> describe('the post controller - Create a file', () => {
>       it('should return a 200 status when all parameters are passed correctly', async () => {
>       const storeFileStub = sinon.stub(fileController, 'validateMyRequest').resolves(Promise.resolve('next()'));
>       await request(app)
>           .post('/')
>           .field('filename', 'testfile')
>           .field('filetype', 'pdf')
>           .attach('input', 'test/test.zip')
>           .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
>                   .set('Authorization', `Bearer wjeijwiejwe`)
>           .expect(200)
>           .expect(response => {
>               assert.deepStrictEqual(response.status, 200);
>           });
>       storeFileStub.restore();
> });
> ```

I tried adding the sinon stub method from as per below but test case is failing
`Error: expected 200 "OK", got 401 "Unauthorized"`

`const storeFileStub = sinon.stub(fileController, 'validateMyRequest').resolves(Promise.resolve('next()'));`